# Alphabetical sorting of UITableView iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` in iOS with a list of clients that I need to sort alphabetically.

The sort button sorts my clients alphabetically:

```
-(void)prepareSortedClients {
    //Check if my clients are sorted, then create the index and clients
    if (!self.alphaKeys) {
        //No list of appropriate characters for side index, create it
        NSMutableSet *alphaSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
        for ( RMClients *thisClient in self.clients )
        {
            if ( thisClient.name > 0 )
                [alphaSet addObject:[thisClient.name substringToIndex:1]];
        }

        NSArray *indexArray = [[alphaSet allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
        self.alphaKeys = indexArray;
    }

    if (!self.sortedClients) {
        //Clients are not sorted, do it
        self.sortedClients = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        //Create a set of all the client objects
        NSSet *allClients = [NSSet setWithArray:self.clients];

        //go through alpha keys and populate Dictionary with the appropriate clients
        for (NSString *thisAlphaKey in self.alphaKeys) {
            //get all clients starting with this key
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name beginswith[c] %@",thisAlphaKey];
            NSSet *filteredSet = [allClients filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];
            //the filteredSet now contains only the clients starting with this letter. Now, sort them and set the sortedClients's corresponding key to this array
            [self.sortedClients setObject:[[filteredSet allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] forKey:thisAlphaKey];    
    }
}
```

This takes care of sorting and everything looks great; my clients are sorted according to the client title with the proper section and everything. The issue I am experiencing is that I have 4 buttons in each cell (it gives you additional info specific info about the company (overview, financials etc).

Now my original list without it being sorted I get these buttons going to the proper place and displaying information about the client in that cell.

Now in the alphabetical sort I get the sort for the client with the letter "A" directed to the proper client page... now if I click on one of the buttons for a specific client under the letter "B" I still get the first client under the letter "A".

So I am not getting that sort for the remaining clients even though they are displayed there.

Any idea where I messed up?

**---Additional code--- (This is where I refer to the buttons in my code)**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    RMCustomClientCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ClientCell"];

    RMClients *client;

    if(!self.alphaMode){
        client = [self.clients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        NSString *key = [self.alphaKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSArray *specificClients = [self.sortedClients objectForKey:key];            
        client = [specificClients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    cell.financialDetailsButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.overviewDetailsButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.pressReleaseDetailsButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.eventsDetailsButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    cell.nameLabel.text = client.name;
    cell.symbolLabel.text = client.symbol;
    [cell.logoView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:client.logoURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This question is not related to Xcode.

Comment: Sounds like the data in each section is not grouped properly. Can you post the code that shows how you reload the table's data after sorting the clients?

Comment: Let me guess: these buttons are stored in the other array than your clients? And when you sort your clients array you reload the `UITableView`? So the text there comes from that **sorted** array of clients and corresponding 4 buttons come from the array(s) that is(are) unsorted. Am I right?

Comment: I added the code where I refer to the buttons... does that help....

Comment: I added additional code to my post,,, please your help would be greatly appreciated.. thanks